# Irreducibility of some polynomial

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebra-precalculus, polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

Let $p(x) = (1+ \cdots +x^k)^2 + (1+ \cdots +x^k) + 1$, for some $k \geq 2$ fixed. I would like to know if $p(x)$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$.

Comment: Hmmm... nothing terribly helpful so far, but one can use Eisenstein at $5$ for $p_{2}(x+2)$ to show $p_{2}(x)$ is irreducible (here, the subscript $2$ refers to the value of $k$). Trying to find a more general pattern...

Comment: Depends on $k,\,$ e.g. $\,x^2\!-x+1\mid p_k(x)\,$ for $\,k=4,10,16,\,$ but all others are irreducible for $\,k\le 16.\ \ $

Comment: Thanks to you both. @Bill, did you get that by applying Eisenstein's criterion?

Comment: @Manolito In fact, the values of $\,k\,$ where it is reducible appear to be the same as [OEIS sequence A016957](https://oeis.org/search?q=4%2C10%2C16%2C22%2C28&language=english&go=Search) up to $\,k = 70,\,$ i.e. $\ 4, 10, 16, 22, 28, 34, 40, 46, 52, 58, 64, 70,\ldots$ So perhaps there is something interesting behind that (I don't have time to look further now). Someone please double-check the computations.